# Android GCM vs Alarms for Notifications

Tags: android, android-notifications, google-cloud-messaging, android-alarms

I'm developing an app where the user receives notifications that are important. I can't really go into details since it's proprietary, but let's just say the notifications would be along the lines of reminding you to give your dog insulin. Pretty important, since your dog needs insulin on time.

I successfully set up notifications based on an alarm:

```
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 16);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,59);

        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
            AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
```

It seems to work reasonably well, but from what I read there are certain instances where alarms might not be scheduled, like after a reboot, or if you force stop the application. There is also the issue of inexact alarms in version 19.

So if anyone has used both Alarms and GoogleCloudMessaging for notifications, it would help if you could advise me as to which method is best when it is imperative that notifications are received in a timely and reliable manner.

Answer (score 2):

Let us sort one after the other

**Alarm**

1. + Doesn't require Internet
2. + We receive alerts On Time
3. - We have to manage TimeZones
4. - manage Phone Restart
5. - App Force Close
6. +- can be more

**GCM**

1. - Requires Internet(Every one has now a days)
2. + GCM pushes get On Time
3. + No TimeZone management
4. + GCM still be received after phone restart
5. - App Force Close will stop GCM
6. - Need to manage GCM functionality

Finally, it depends on how important the app is to the end user.

Comment: `No Force Close can stop GCM` - that's not true. GCM will stop working when you force close the app, and won't start working again until the user re-launches the app. This has been true since Android 3.1

Comment: Thankx @Eran for correcting me. That's a thing I learned today :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to write the service. Then you mention in your AndroidManifest file, like as a service

```
<service android:name="com.sample.ClassName" >
        </service>
```